# Check if parent thread is running

Tags: python, multithreading

I am wondering how to check to see if a parent thread is still alive/stuck. Basically I have a parent thread sending commands to a child. If parent thread dies or hits a deadlock condition I do not want the child to continue to live. Below is basic framework of my implementation thus far.

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

    class myClass:

        def __init__(self):

            self.currentCommand = Queue()           
            t = Thread(target=self._run)
            t.start()            

        def close(self):
            self._sendCommand("close")

        def _run(self):
            while True:
                if self.currentCommand.empty():
                    pass
                    #do some task
                else:
                    command = self.currentCommand.get()
                    if command == "close":
                        #clean up
                        self.currentCommand.task_done()
                        break
                    else:
                        #do command task
                        self.currentCommand.task_done()

        def _sendCommand(self, command):
            self.currentCommand.put(command)
            self.currentCommand.join()
```

One idea I have is to periodically send computer time to child from parent. If time is greater than a set value child will die. Is there a easier or more effect method? Also within the python documentation, there is an isAlive method within the threading class but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass an [`Event`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) object down to the child thread, which it can check to see if the parent indicated a quit. Then you just wrap the critical section in the parent thread with a `finally` that will set the bit no matter what:

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event


def child(quit):
    for _ in xrange(10):
        if quit.isSet():
            print "Parent is dead. Leaving child."
            return

        print "Child alive"
        time.sleep(.5)

def parent():
    quitEvent = Event()
    t = Thread(target=child, args=(quitEvent,))
    t.start()

    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        raise Exception("Parent thread raises exception")
    finally:
        quitEvent.set()

    t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Thread(target=parent, args=())
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Though the matter of the parent thread dead-locking during it's own work would probably require a "heartbeat" approach like you suggested, where it is periodically indicating that it is alive. You could do that with either the queue that you pass down to the child, or you can continue to use the Event object. The parent would periodically set the event, and the child would expect it to be set at certain intervals, and then would clear it right after.

Here is an example of using the `Event` as a heartbeat, in the case where the parent might be deadlocked and not checking in:

```
def child(heartbeat):
    for _ in xrange(10):
        if not heartbeat.isSet():
            print "Parent is dead. Leaving child."
            return

        heartbeat.clear()

        print "Child alive"
        time.sleep(1)

def parent():
    heartbeat = Event()
    heartbeat.set()

    t = Thread(target=child, args=(heartbeat,))
    t.start()

    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        print "Parent alive"
        i += 1
        heartbeat.set()
        time.sleep(.1)

    print "Parent done looping...pretending to be deadlocked"
    time.sleep(5)

    t.join()
```

As the parent is doing it's own work, it is setting the heartbeat bit. The child is checking for this bit periodically. If it finds the parent is not set, then it assumes it is dead and quits. You would need to establish a heartbeat interval that is appropriate. The parent needs to check in more often than the child is checking it, or the child might check to soon and think the parent is gone.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use `isAlife` if you somehow share parent thread object with child:

```
parent_thread = None

def child():
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       if not parent_thread.isAlive():
           break
       print('child alife')


def parent():
    t = threading.Thread(target=child)
    t.start()
    for i in range(10):
        print('parent alife')
        time.sleep(1)

parent_thread = threading.Thread(target=parent)
parent_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line:

```
threading.main_thread().is_alive()
```